# how to iterate one arraylist from another one and want to display the value as shown below?

Tags: java

### Sample Output:

```
Department name : CSE
Student Count   : 4
Department name : EEE
Student Count   : 2
```

### My Code

```
public class Student {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String department;

    public Student(int id, String name, String department) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.department = department;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

}


public class Department {


    private String name;
    private int studentCount;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getStudentCount() {
        return studentCount;
    }

    public void setStudentCount(int studentCount) {
        this.studentCount = studentCount;
    }


}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        students.add(new Student(1, "aaa", "CSE"));
        students.add(new Student(2, "bbb", "EEE"));
        students.add(new Student(3, "bbb", "IT"));
        students.add(new Student(4, "ddd", "CSE"));
        students.add(new Student(5, "eee", "MC"));
        students.add(new Student(6, "fff", "IT"));
        students.add(new Student(7, "ggg", "EEE"));
        students.add(new Student(8, "hhh", "CSE"));
        students.add(new Student(9, "iii", "IT"));
        students.add(new Student(10, "jjj", "EC"));
        students.add(new Student(11, "kkk", "CSE"));


        List<Department> departments = new ArrayList<Department>();

//The output should be printed from here

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in terms of OOP, it would be must better if your `Student` class will have a `Department` class reference, and not just a department string name. That way the connection between the two objects will be much simpler, and you won't have to go through the horrors of string comparison.

Better yet, simply have your `Department` class object hold a `List<Student>` object, and not just the count. That way, your connections will be much stronger.

In your current implementation, for instance you could have a student enrolled in a department that does not exist and have more students in a department than actually are connected to it.

Currently, since there is no real connection between the two objects, it seems all your output should be is scanning *one* list - the department list:

```
for (Department department : departments) {
    System.out.println("Department name : " + department.getName());
    System.out.println("Student Count   : " + department.getStudentCount());
}
```

If your question however is how you populate your departments list given the student list, then I would keep a map and then populate the list:

```
Map<String, Integer> studentsInDepartments = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for (Student student : students) {
    String department = student.getDepartment();
    if (studentsInDepartments.containsKey(department)) {
        studentsInDepartments.put(department, studentsInDepartments.get(department) + 1);
    } else {
        studentsInDepartments.put(department, 1);
    }
}

for (String key : studentsInDepartments.keySet()) {
    Department department = new Department();
    department.setName(key);
    department.setStudentCount(studentsInDepartments.get(key));
}
```

As you can see, this is "not so pretty". I believe it would be better for you, both here and in general, to fix the object structure to be more object-oriented.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
        List<Department> departments = new ArrayList<Department>();
        Department dep = new Department();
        dep.setName("CSE");
        dep.setStudentCount(4);
        departments.add(dep);

        dep = new Department();
        dep.setName("EEE");
        dep.setStudentCount(2);
        departments.add(dep);

        for(Department dept : departments) {
            System.out.println("Department Name : " + dept.getName());
            System.out.println("Student Count   : " + dept.getStudentCount());
        }
```

**Output**

> Department Name : CSE
>
> Student Count   : 4
>
> Department Name : EEE
>
> Student Count   : 2

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of what you want. It will populate departments from the list of students

```
public class DepartmentExample
{  

  public void doTheWork()
  {
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    students.add(new Student(1, "aaa", "CSE"));
    students.add(new Student(2, "bbb", "EEE"));
    students.add(new Student(3, "bbb", "IT"));
    students.add(new Student(4, "ddd", "CSE"));
    students.add(new Student(5, "eee", "MC"));
    students.add(new Student(6, "fff", "IT"));
    students.add(new Student(7, "ggg", "EEE"));
    students.add(new Student(8, "hhh", "CSE"));
    students.add(new Student(9, "iii", "IT"));
    students.add(new Student(10, "jjj", "EC"));
    students.add(new Student(11, "kkk", "CSE"));

    List<Department> departments = populateDepartmentsFromStudentsList(students);

    for (Department department : departments)
    {
      System.out.println("Department name :" +department.getName() );
      System.out.println("Student Count   :" +department.getStudentCount() );
    }
  }

  private List<Department> populateDepartmentsFromStudentsList(List<Student> students)
  {
    List<Department> departments = new ArrayList<Department>();

    for (Student student : students)
    {
      Department department = getDepartmentByName(departments, student.department);
      if (department == null)
      {
        department = new Department();
        department.setName(student.getDepartment());
        departments.add(department);
      }
      department.setStudentCount(department.getStudentCount() + 1);
    }
    return departments;
  }

  private Department getDepartmentByName(List<Department> departments, String departmentName)
  {
    for (Department department : departments)
    {
      if (department.getName().equals(departmentName))
      {
        return department;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    DepartmentExample departmentExample = new DepartmentExample();
    departmentExample.doTheWork();
  }

}
```

Comment: @Balamanikandan To accept the answer, you click the tick so that it turns green.

Comment: Sorry Evan just now I accepted thanks for your help.